# 【CVAT】How to create multiple jobs in one task?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, data-annotations

As per the introduction of CAVT, it can be created many jobs into one task, but I can't find any button for creating more jobs, how can I do it?

[image: Task details]

Answer (score 12):

Please specify the `segment size` when you create a task (e.g. 1000). It is not possible to add more jobs after a task is created at the moment.

https://github.com/opencv/cvat/blob/master/cvat/apps/documentation/user_guide.md

> Segment size. Use this option to divide a huge dataset into a few smaller segments. For example, one job cannot be annotated by several labelers (it isn't supported). Thus using "segment size" you can create several jobs for the same annotation task. It will help you to parallel data annotation process.

Comment: What if you need the same data to be annotated by multiple annotators (e.g. four annotators)?

Answer (score 3):

You split it by giving a segment size.
Then it is adding jobs automatically when you upload